# Why this replace(), re.sub() or strip() do not work with this string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, replace, trim, strip

I'm using BeautifulSoup to get a result from a webpage. I've transformed the data object to string and I'm not being able to trim it.

I've got the following string:

`text = '\n\n\n        This product is not available.\n      \n'`

I've tried three options to start removing the newline character:

1. `string=text.replace('\n','')`
2. `string=text.strip('\n')`
3. 

```
import re
string = re.sub('\n','', text)
```

Why *string* output is still the same as *text* in all cases? I haven't understood the logic yet.

Does someone know what's happening?

UPDATE:
THe whole programming text in case it allows to reproduce:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

resp = requests.get('https://soysuper.com/p/granola-con-avena-y-frutos-rojos-kellogg-s-special-k-320-g-320-g', headers={'User-Agent':'Chrome/44.0.2403.157','Accept-Language': 'es-ES, es;q=0.5'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode('UTF-8'),'html.parser')

data = [element.text for element in soup.find_all("section", {"class": "display display--coco"})]

text=str(data)

#option1
string=text.replace('\n',' ')
#option2
string=text.strip('\n')
#option3
string = re.sub('\n','', text)

print(string)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. `text.strip()` removes the whitespaces.

Comment: Are you sure the string you're dealing with is *actually* what you're showing? Depending on where you're getting it from, the `\n`'s might be an actual backslash followed by an actual `n` character.

Comment: @Blckknght you nailed it, they're actually blackslash and n characters when turned to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.getText(strip=True)`.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://soysuper.com/p/granola-con-avena-y-frutos-rojos-kellogg-s-special-k-320-g-320-g', headers={'User-Agent':'Chrome/44.0.2403.157','Accept-Language': 'es-ES, es;q=0.5'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode('UTF-8'),'html.parser')

data = [element.getText(strip=True) for element in soup.find_all("section", {"class": "display display--coco"})]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Este producto no está disponible en ningún supermercado online.']
```

Comment: Thank god! This was driving me crazy!!